# Highlight textboxes after validation error

Tags: javascript, html

Taking info from this question.

I have 10 items that an isNaN function will validate, if a validation error occurs the textbox should be highlighted. My question is:

Is there code that will highlight any wrong text boxes easily? Or will I have to write out code for all 10 items? The JS code that follows is the isNaN function, and so far the item numCoke will be highlighted.

```
if (
    isNaN(document.drinkList.numFruit.value)
    || isNaN(document.drinkList.numWater.value)
    || isNaN(document.drinkList.numCoffee.value)
    || isNaN(document.drinkList.numCoke.value)
    || isNaN(document.drinkList.numTea.value)
    || isNaN(document.drinkList.numIce.value)
    || isNaN(document.drinkList.numCream.value)
    || isNaN(document.drinkList.numSugar.value)
    || isNaN(document.drinkList.numPinn.value)
    || isNaN(document.drinkList.numLemon.value)
) {
    window.alert("You must enter a numeric value!");
    document.drinkList.numCoke.style.borderColor = "red";
    document.drinkList.numCoke.style.backgroundColor = "red";

    return false;
}
```

The HTML code, only showing the first 5 items, the rest are identical.

```
<p>
    <input type="text" name="numFruit" size="3" value="0" /> Fruit Drink: A delicious mixture of various fruit juices. ($5.00)
    <br />

    <input type="text" name="numWater" size="3" value="0" /> Water: Crystal clear spring water. ($1.00)
    <br />

    <input type="text" name="numCoffee" size="3" value="0" /> Coffee: Freshly made coffee. ($4.00)
    <br />

    <input type="text" name="numCoke" size="3" value="0" /> Coke: Classic Coca-Cola. ($3.00)
    <br />

    <input type="text" name="numTea" size="3" value="0" /> Tea: Freshly made tea. ($2.00)
    <br />
</p>
```

Comment: Depending on the browser support you require, there is a [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern) attribute you can use to validate input areas with a special [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ainvalid) selector for fields who do not match the pattern.

Comment: This might help! https://jsfiddle.net/xp59fdpa/

Comment: I appreciate it Rayon Dabre, however I'm only supposed to use JS and HTML, any insight?

Comment: Please never put so much `if ( || )` `OR` conditions in the same `if` like that, and so badly *indented*.
Keep your code simple

Comment: I figured it was very messy. Any suggestions?

Comment: By wrong textboxes what do you mean exactly?

Comment: It will highlight any textbox that is not an integer. So say like 7 textboxes have a valid input, while 3 dont. Those 3 will then be highlighted

Comment: And you can't use css?

Comment: You might find this useful, you can use JS for validity http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp

Answer (score 0):

By changing the `type` attribute from text to number, this will highlight the `input` element as red. An exmaple from your code would be

```
<input type="number" name="numFruit" size="3" value="0" /> Fruit Drink: A delicious mixture of various fruit juices. ($5.00)
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMvWWO)

Comment: I should have been more clear, the input type also needs to remain text.

Comment: Ok grand, but previously you stated you only wanted integers. Using text allows other characters to be inserted into the input box

Answer (score 0):

that's what you want ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
   $('#form-test').submit(function(e){
    
    var error = false;
    
    if( $('input[name=field1]').val()==0 ) { 
     document.getElementsByName("field1")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
     document.getElementsByName("field1")[0].style.borderColor = "red";
     error = true;
    }else{
     document.getElementsByName("field1")[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
     document.getElementsByName("field1")[0].style.borderColor = "white";
     error = false;
    }
    if( $('input[name=field2]').val()==0 ) { 
     document.getElementsByName("field2")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
     document.getElementsByName("field2")[0].style.borderColor = "red";
     error = true;
    }else{
     document.getElementsByName("field2")[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
     document.getElementsByName("field2")[0].style.borderColor = "white";
     error = false;
    }
    if( $('input[name=field3]').val()==0 ) { 
     document.getElementsByName("field3")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
     document.getElementsByName("field3")[0].style.borderColor = "red";
     error = true;
    }else{
     document.getElementsByName("field3")[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
     document.getElementsByName("field3")[0].style.borderColor = "white";
     error = false;
    }
    if( $('input[name=field4]').val()==0 ) { 
     document.getElementsByName("field4")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
     document.getElementsByName("field4")[0].style.borderColor = "red";
     error = true;
    }else{
     document.getElementsByName("field4")[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
     document.getElementsByName("field4")[0].style.borderColor = "white";
     error = false;
    }
    if( $('input[name=field5]').val()==0 ) { 
     document.getElementsByName("field5")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
     document.getElementsByName("field5")[0].style.borderColor = "red";
     error = true;
    }else{
     document.getElementsByName("field5")[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
     document.getElementsByName("field5")[0].style.borderColor = "white";
     error = false;
    }
    if( $('input[name=fieldn]').val()==0 ) { 
     document.getElementsByName("fieldn")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
     document.getElementsByName("fieldn")[0].style.borderColor = "red";
     error = true;
    }else{
     document.getElementsByName("fieldn")[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
     document.getElementsByName("fieldn")[0].style.borderColor = "white";
     error = false;
    }

    if(error) { e.preventDefault(); alert('You must enter a numeric value!'); }
    
   });
  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <form id="form-test">
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Just Example</legend>
    <div class="field">
     <label>Field 1 : </label>
      <input type="number" name="field1" value="0" min="0" max="999">
     </div>
     <div class="field">
      <label>Field 2 : </label>
      <input type="number" name="field2" value="0" min="0" max="999">
     </div>
     <div class="field">
      <label>Field 3 : </label>
      <input type="number" name="field3" value="0" min="0" max="999">
     </div>
     <div class="field">
      <label>Field 4 : </label>
      <input type="number" name="field4" value="0" min="0" max="999">
     </div>
     <div class="field">
      <label>Field 5 : </label>
      <input type="number" name="field5" value="0" min="0" max="999">
     </div>
     <div class="field">
      <label>Field n : </label>
      <input type="number" name="fieldn" value="0" min="0" max="999">
     </div>

     <button type="submit" id="validate">Validate</button>
   </fieldset>    
  </form>
  </div>
  
    
</body>
</html>
```